# Format double value in different locale

Tags: c++, localization

In my C++ project I am using string formatting as follows -

```
sprintf(tag, "%g", "100.88");
```

If I run it in English locale it maps fine. I would like to make changes to it to work in different locales. Like in German locale tag should get assigned as 100,88.

How I can achieve this?

I am looking for something similar to

```
system.convert.tostring(100.88 , 
                        system.globalization.culturalinfo.invariantculture)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an `ostringstream` imbued with the locale you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you were using [iostreams](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io), you'd do this by [imbuing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/imbue) the stream with the [locale](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) you want to use.

Comment: Thank You all for your replies. Can anybody provide me working example? as my search is returning examples not relavent to my case. THANKS A LOT