# how to convert string to double with certain delimeter?

Tags: c++

On my maching this code (note "," and "."):

```
std::cout << std::stod("0.055") << "   " << std::stod("0,055") << std::endl;
```

Produce:

```
0   0.055
```

How can I convert "0.055" to double on my machine?

Comment: Maybe try calling `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");` before that?

Comment: I have `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");` cause I need to print russian strings

Comment: I don't think you can support both formats (0.5 and 0,5) on the same stream, but you can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13911964/596167 on a separate stringstream (or you can switch the locales when you need to output such a number).

Comment: probably i can just use some another function, not std::stod? but atof doesn't work too

Comment: atof still depends on your Russian locale. You can write a function that creates a stream with the string contents, imbues a "C" locale (or any other locale with a . instead of ,) and then read a double number from the stream.

Comment: i've used this and it works http://stackoverflow.com/a/12317183/93647 However it's strange that I can not set a delimeter. In C# I can pass parameter something like "Culture.InvariantCulture" - very handy.